# My program will not display any output

Tags: java

My code compiles, but the output won't show. I think my methods are all correct, but I have no idea why my output will not display. (NB: beginner in Java)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Lab8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double radius;
        double height;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter radius: ");
        radius = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter height: ");
        height = in.nextDouble();
    }

    public static double Calculations(double radius, double height) {
        double surfaceArea = (2 * Math.PI * radius * radius) + (2 * Math.PI * radius * height);
        return surfaceArea;
    }

    public static double calculations(double radius, double height) {

        double volume = Math.PI * radius * radius * height;
        return volume;
    }

    public static void output(double surfaceArea, double volume) {
        System.out.println("Surface Area of Cylinder: " + surfaceArea);
        System.out.println("Voulme of Cylinder: " + volume);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you now.  What fix did you apply?

Comment: I added the calls to the main as suggested :    /*System.out.println("surfaceArea " + Calculations(radius,height));
   System.out.println("volume " +calculations(radius,height));//

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call any of your helper functions within `main(...)`.  Try adding a call to `output` or `calculations` within your main function.

In particular, something like

```
output(Calculations(radius, height), calculations(radius, height));
```

will probably suffice.

As you learn Java, it may be helpful to begin applying descriptive names to your functions, such as `CylinderSurfaceArea` to help keep confusion to a minimum both for you and for anyone who might read code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually *call* your methods.

In `main`, after you get the `radius` and `height`, call `Calculations` and `calculations` respectively, with the appropriate arguments.

Here's an example:

```
surfaceArea = Calculations(radius, height);
volume = calculations(radius, height);
```

Comment: would my call look something like: double volume = calculations

Comment: @VeronicaFelix: yes, that would be an appropriate way to call the function, except that it needs arguments...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your method inside main to print the value.

```
   System.out.println("surfacearea " + Calculations(radius,height));
   System.out.println("volume " +calculations(radius,height));
   System.out.println("output "  + output(radius,height));
```

Fixed Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.lang.Math;
   public class Lab8
   {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

   double radius;
   double height;

   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter radius: ");
   radius= in.nextDouble();
   System.out.print("Enter height: ");
   height= in.nextDouble();
   System.out.println("surfacearea " + Calculations(radius,height));
   System.out.println("volume " +calculations(radius,height));
   System.out.println("output "  + output(radius,height));
   }
   public static double Calculations(double radius, double height)
   {
   double surfaceArea= (2 * Math.PI * radius * radius) + (2 * Math.PI *radius* height);           
   return surfaceArea;
   }
   public static double calculations(double radius,double height)
   {

   double volume= Math.PI * radius * radius * height;
   return volume;
   }
   public static void output(double surfaceArea, double volume)
   {
   System.out.println("Surface Area of Cylinder: " + surfaceArea);
   System.out.println("Voulme of Cylinder: " + volume);
    }
      }
```

Comment: thank you I fixed it. I removed the System.out.println("output" +output(radius, height)); and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Try calling one of your Calculations method in your main method, post taking the input such as:

```
System.out.println(Lab8.Calculations(radius,height));
```

Comment: Calculations is a static method,so i think we can directly write **System.out.println(Calculations(radius,height));**

Answer (score 0):

In main you miss the calculate and output method call

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{    
   double radius;
   double height;

   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter radius: ");
   radius= in.nextDouble();
   System.out.print("Enter height: ");
   height= in.nextDouble();
   // call this 
   System.out.println("area " + output(Calculations(radius,height)));
}
```